# Rails model serialize before storing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've been trying to serialize a column before I put it in the database. I wanted to do the following in my model:

```
class SearchResult < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :data
end
```

...but it wouldn't serialize when I save. So I resorted to this:

```
class SearchResult < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :serialize_data

  private
    def serialize_data
      self.data = YAML.dump self.data
    end
end
```

This works. But, is there any reason why the top code doesn't work (it's much neater), or do I need to declare the serialize method? It doesn't throw any errors, but doesn't do what I hoped it would do either.

Comment: No it should work, have you tried setting the object you want to serialize `serialize :data, Array`?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
class SearchResult < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :data, Hash
end
```

Comment: Gives me an error `ActiveRecord::SerializationTypeMismatch:
       Attribute was supposed to be a Hash, but was a String` when I run my tests and in the app

Comment: What is your data object? What do you assign to it?

Comment: I'm using Google API client to make a request to the YouTube API. My data object is what I get back from that `[#<Google::APIClient::Schema::Youtube::V3::SearchResult:0x3fcb7a6b5654 DATA:{"kind"=>"youtube#searchResult", "etag"=>"\"ePFRUfYBkeQ2ncpP9...` (from abort). The data I get back I want to be available in session. Ofcourse I can't put it in session variable so I thought to write it to the DB and retrieve it later in another page.

Comment: You need to specify what class the data object is. Try `serialize :data, Google::APIClient::Schema::Youtube::V3::SearchResult`

Comment: No, that gave me errors too - `{uninitialized constant Google::APIClient::Schema::Youtube (NameError)`. Perhaps it doesn't like this object too well, YAML works fine anyway.

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
class SearchResult < ActiveRecord::Base
  store :data, accessors: [:data_help]
end
```